# Tokenizing and parsing a text file (edit decision list ASCII text file) Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, parsing, ascii, tokenize

I'm new to programming and stackoverflow and have decided to start by learning objective c.

In at the deep end, I know.

I am stuck trying to work out the best way to parse an edl file.
It is basically an ASCII text file of no more than 100KB.
Here is the structure of a typical cmx3600 edl:

```
TITLE:   EP1 FINAL.EDL SECTION2
FCM: NON-DROP FRAME
001  A199_C00 V     C        20:38:24:15 20:38:26:04 10:30:00:02 10:30:01:16
* SOURCE FILE: A199_C008_0915AH_001
002  A199_C00 V     C        20:34:48:17 20:34:51:23 10:30:01:16 10:30:04:22
* SOURCE FILE: A199_C007_0915VE_001
```

I'm trying to work out the best way to parse or scan each element into fields/arrays ie,

```
editNum = 001
tapeName = A199_C00
channel = V
Operation = C
sourceIn = 20:38:24:15
sourceOut = 20:38:26:04
recIn = 10:30:00:02
recOut = 10:30:01:16
sourceFile = A199_C008_0915AH_001
```

This is my code so far:

```
-(IBAction)importEdl:(id)sender {    

    //defines an Array of allowed file types with file extension ".EDL and .edl"

    NSOpenPanel *myPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    NSArray *fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"EDL", @"edl", nil];
    myPanel.allowedFileTypes = fileTypes;
    myPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;

    if ([myPanel runModal] == NSOKButton)
    {            

    NSString *theFilePath = [myPanel filename];
    NSString *psEdlFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:theFilePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
        // Reads the file as one string. EDL's are simple ASCII text files of roughly 50KB.

    NSArray *psEdlLines = [psEdlFile componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];   
        // Separates the data into lines.

    if([psEdlLines count] == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error!");                                  
    } //prints error if EDL file has no events.


    NSUInteger count;
    int i;
    for (i = 0, count = [psEdlLines count]; i < count; i = i + 1)
    {
        NSString *lineStrings = [psEdlLines objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Line %d is %@",i+1,lineStrings);

    //NSArray *linesEnum = [psEdlLines objectAtIndex:i];
        //this creates an array of lines

    //NSLog(@"index is: %d %@",i, linesEnum);
    }

    }                

}

@end
```

The output is:

```
2012-03-20 15:22:08.956 TestProgram[412:903] Line 1 is TITLE:   EP1 FINAL.EDL SECTION2
2012-03-20 15:22:08.957 TestProgram[412:903] Line 2 is FCM: NON-DROP FRAME
2012-03-20 15:22:08.957 TestProgram[412:903] Line 3 is 001  A199_C00 V     C        20:38:24:15 20:38:26:04 10:30:00:02 10:30:01:16
2012-03-20 15:22:08.957 TestProgram[412:903] Line 4 is * SOURCE FILE: A199_C008_0915AH_001
2012-03-20 15:22:08.957 TestProgram[412:903] Line 5 is 002  A199_C00 V     C        20:34:48:17 20:34:51:23 10:30:01:16 10:30:04:22
2012-03-20 15:22:08.957 TestProgram[412:903] Line 6 is * SOURCE FILE: A199_C007_0915VE_001
2012-03-20 15:22:08.957 TestProgram[412:903] Line 7 is 003  A199_C00 V     C        20:42:32:01 20:42:35:19 10:30:04:22 10:30:08:15
2012-03-20 15:22:08.957 TestProgram[412:903] Line 8 is * SOURCE FILE: A199_C009_0915RX_001
2012-03-20 15:22:08.957 TestProgram[412:903] Line 9 is 
2012-03-20 15:22:08.958 TestProgram[412:903] Line 10 is
```

I haven't got very far as you can see.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Pete.

Comment: If you are doing parsing, the way to go is a BNF grammar. Constructing one and using it will be a very good learning exercise.

Comment: Look at [ParseKit](http://www.parsekit.com/).

Comment: Or, `NSScanner` if you are new to the Cocoa and want to get your feet wet with the native frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replys. Looks like i've got a bit of reading to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More Progress.

```
if ([lineScanner scanInt:&eventNum])
    {
        // parse the event into fields

        // does not work if edl contains dissolve or wipe
        // need to automatically convert dissolves into cuts

         NSString *editNum;
         NSString *reelName;
         NSString *channels;
         NSString *operation;
         //NSString *opDuration;
         NSString *sourceInTime;
         NSString *sourceOutTime;
         NSString *destInTime;
         NSString *destOutTime;

        NSScanner *elementScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:line];

        //NSString *token = [NSString string];
        NSCharacterSet *divider = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];

        [elementScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:divider intoString:&editNum];
        [elementScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:divider intoString:&reelName];
        [elementScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:divider intoString:&channels];
        [elementScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:divider intoString:&operation];
        //[elementScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:divider intoString:&opDuration];
        [elementScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:divider intoString:&sourceInTime];
        [elementScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:divider intoString:&sourceOutTime];
        [elementScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:divider intoString:&destInTime];
        [elementScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:divider intoString:&destOutTime];


        NSLog(@"Event\tReelName\tChannels\tOperation\tSource In\tSource Out\tDest In\t\tDest Out");
        NSLog(@"%@\t%@\t%@\t\t\t%@\t\t\t%@\t%@\t%@\t%@", 
              editNum, reelName, channels, operation, /*opDuration,*/ sourceInTime, sourceOutTime, destInTime,destOutTime);

    }
```

Outputs the following.

```
2012-03-29 15:54:15.489 TestProgram[2414:903] Scanner:Title = EP1 FINAL.EDL SECTION2
2012-03-29 15:54:15.489 TestProgram[2414:903] Event ReelName    Channels    Operation   Source In   Source Out  Dest In     Dest Out
2012-03-29 15:54:15.489 TestProgram[2414:903] 001   A180_C00    V           C           20:29:12:18 20:29:13:21 10:46:39:20 10:46:40:23
2012-03-29 15:54:15.489 TestProgram[2414:903] Comment for event    001 * SOURCE FILE: A180_C001_09138L_001
2012-03-29 15:54:15.489 TestProgram[2414:903] Event ReelName    Channels    Operation   Source In   Source Out  Dest In     Dest Out
2012-03-29 15:54:15.490 TestProgram[2414:903] 002   A181_C01    V           C           22:10:03:03 22:10:05:09 10:46:40:23 10:46:43:04
2012-03-29 15:54:15.490 TestProgram[2414:903] Comment for event    002 * SOURCE FILE: A181_C010_0913EA_001
2012-03-29 15:54:15.490 TestProgram[2414:903] Event ReelName    Channels    Operation   Source In   Source Out  Dest In     Dest Out
2012-03-29 15:54:15.490 TestProgram[2414:903] 003   A181_C01    V           C           22:10:05:09 22:10:05:10 10:46:43:04 10:46:43:09
2012-03-29 15:54:15.490 TestProgram[2414:903] Effect for event     003    M2   A181_C01       000.0                22:10:05:09
2012-03-29 15:54:15.491 TestProgram[2414:903] Comment for event    003 * * FREEZE FRAME
2012-03-29 15:54:15.491 TestProgram[2414:903] Comment for event    003 * SOURCE FILE: A181_C010_0913EA_001
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I've been trying to figure this out by using NSScanner and line prefixes.
I can scan lines (events) that begin with a number and also isolate comment and effect associated with each corresponding event.

here's the code:

```
for (NSString *line in psEdlLines)// just an NSLog test before scanning process 
    {
        NSLog(@"Before scanner: %@",line);//All lines.
    }

for (NSString *line in psEdlLines)// Scanner process.
        {

        int eventNum;
        NSString *comment;
        NSString *effect;
        NSScanner *lineScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:line];

while ([lineScanner scanInt:&eventNum]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Scanner: Event only: %@:", line);
        }

    if ([line hasPrefix:@"*"]) 
        {
                comment = [line substringFromIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"Comment for event    %03i: %@",eventNum, comment);
        }

    if ([line hasPrefix:@"M2"]) 
            {
                effect = [line substringFromIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"Effect for event     %03i:    %@",eventNum, effect);
            }
}
@end
```

Here's the output from a 3 event edl file:

```
2012-03-23 14:23:48.040 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: TITLE:   EP1 FINAL.EDL SECTION2
2012-03-23 14:23:48.040 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: FCM: NON-DROP FRAME
2012-03-23 14:23:48.040 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: 001  A180_C00 V     C        20:29:12:18 20:29:13:21 10:46:39:20 10:46:40:23
2012-03-23 14:23:48.040 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: * SOURCE FILE: A180_C001_09138L_001
2012-03-23 14:23:48.040 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: 002  A181_C01 V     C        22:10:03:03 22:10:05:09 10:46:40:23 10:46:43:04
2012-03-23 14:23:48.040 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: * SOURCE FILE: A181_C010_0913EA_001
2012-03-23 14:23:48.040 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: 003  A181_C01 V     C        22:10:05:09 22:10:05:10 10:46:43:04 10:46:43:09
2012-03-23 14:23:48.040 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: M2   A181_C01       000.0                22:10:05:09
2012-03-23 14:23:48.041 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: * * FREEZE FRAME
2012-03-23 14:23:48.041 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: * SOURCE FILE: A181_C010_0913EA_001
2012-03-23 14:23:48.041 TestProgram[1621:903] Before scanner: 
2012-03-23 14:23:48.041 TestProgram[1621:903] Scanner: Event only: 001  A180_C00 V     C        20:29:12:18 20:29:13:21 10:46:39:20 10:46:40:23:
2012-03-23 14:23:48.041 TestProgram[1621:903] Comment for event    001 * SOURCE FILE: A180_C001_09138L_001
2012-03-23 14:23:48.041 TestProgram[1621:903] Scanner: Event only: 002  A181_C01 V     C        22:10:03:03 22:10:05:09 10:46:40:23 10:46:43:04:
2012-03-23 14:23:48.041 TestProgram[1621:903] Comment for event    002 * SOURCE FILE: A181_C010_0913EA_001
2012-03-23 14:23:48.042 TestProgram[1621:903] Scanner: Event only: 003  A181_C01 V     C        22:10:05:09 22:10:05:10 10:46:43:04 10:46:43:09:
2012-03-23 14:23:48.042 TestProgram[1621:903] Effect for event     003    M2   A181_C01       000.0                22:10:05:09
2012-03-23 14:23:48.042 TestProgram[1621:903] Comment for event    003 * * FREEZE FRAME
2012-03-23 14:23:48.042 TestProgram[1621:903] Comment for event    003 * SOURCE FILE: A181_C010_0913EA_001
```

I can add if statements for all eventualities that can arise from comment lines of an edl file.
This should allow me to process each line element as needed within the loop.

Does this look okay?

Thanks,
Pete.